# r caret package, error if I specified index for both rfe control and train control

Tags: r, package, r-caret

I'm getting error when I specified index for rfe.control and train.control

For making glmnet rfe function I coded

```
glmnetFuncs <- caretFuncs #Default caret functions

glmnetFuncs$summary <-  twoClassSummary
```

For specifying index for rfe.control

```
MyRFEcontrol <- rfeControl(
  method="LGOCV",
  number=5,
  index=RFE_CV_IN,
  functions = glmnetFuncs,
  verbose = TRUE)
```

For specifying index for train.control

```
MyTrainControl=trainControl(
  method="LGOCV",
  index=indexIN,
  classProbs = TRUE,
  summaryFunction=twoClassSummary
)
```

Since the data size is big, I just choose random 3 columns to make sure that it works,

```
x=train_v_final4[,c(1,30,55)]
y=TARGET


RFE <- rfe(x=x,y=y,sizes = seq(2,3,by=1),
           metric = 'ROC',maximize=TRUE,rfeControl = MyRFEcontrol,
           method='glmnet',
          # tuneGrid = expand.grid(.alpha=c(0,0.1,1),.lambda=c(0.1,0.01,0.05)),
           trControl = MyTrainControl)
```

But I'm having an error saying

```
**model fit failed for a: alpha=0.10, lambda=3 Error in if (!all(o)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**
```

I tried all other possible ways.

1. specifying index in rfe.control and train.Control ,
2. specifying index in rfe.control but not in train.control,
3. specifying index in train.control but not in rfe.control.

However, non of them works. But it works fine if I use these index list in train() function. Does anyone know what I need to fix? Any comments/thoughts are much appreciated !

Details

```
> nearZeroVar(x[indexIN[[1]],])
integer(0) #other results (nearZeroVar(x[indexIN[[2]],])..etc...)are omitted since the             outputs are identical. 

> cor(x[indexIN[[1]],])
                         id category_q total_spent_90
id             1.0000000000  0.0300781   0.0001837173
category_q     0.0300781045  1.0000000   0.4102276754
total_spent_90 0.0001837173  0.4102277   1.0000000000

> nearZeroVar(x[RFE_CV_IN[[1]],])
integer(0)

> cor(x[RFE_CV_IN[[1]],])
                          id  category_q total_spent_90
id              1.0000000000 0.002903591  -0.0004827006
category_q      0.0029035912 1.000000000   0.9612495056
total_spent_90 -0.0004827006 0.961249506   1.0000000000


> str(RFE_CV_IN)
List of 20
 $ Resample01: int [1:28670] 8 12 35 39 47 51 55 66 71 76 ...
 $ Resample02: int [1:28670] 1 5 7 38 39 49 55 76 91 100 ...
 $ Resample03: int [1:28670] 1 5 7 8 18 30 38 39 49 63 ...
 $ Resample04: int [1:28670] 9 12 18 24 30 35 38 39 49 51 ...
 $ Resample05: int [1:28670] 8 30 47 49 51 63 71 76 77 92 ...
 $ Resample06: int [1:28670] 1 18 30 39 49 55 63 66 71 77 ...
 $ Resample07: int [1:28670] 5 18 24 25 51 76 91 101 112 116 ...
 $ Resample08: int [1:28670] 1 5 7 12 24 25 38 39 49 51 ...
 $ Resample09: int [1:28670] 8 18 24 25 38 49 51 76 101 113 ...
 ....omit rest...

> str(indexIN)
List of 20
 $ Resample01: int [1:64024] 1 6 11 12 14 15 17 19 20 22 ...
 $ Resample02: int [1:64024] 8 11 13 14 18 19 21 22 24 25 ...
 $ Resample03: int [1:64024] 1 3 4 6 11 13 14 15 16 21 ...
 $ Resample04: int [1:64024] 3 9 11 12 13 14 22 24 26 28 ...
.....omit rest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that the outer function (`rfe`) uses the same row indicators as the original data but, once `train` sees the data, those row numbers don't mean the same thing.

Suppose you have 100 data points and are doing 10-fold CV and the first fold is 1-10, the second is 11-20 etc.

On the first fold, `rfe` passes rows 11-100 to `train`. If the `index` vector in `train` has any indices > 90, there will be an error. If not, it may run but not with the rows that you originally told `train` to use.

You could do this but it will require a separate set of resample indices for each resample of the outer model (i.e. `ref`) since the inner data will be different each time. Also, you would need to be really careful if you do bootstrapping since it samples with replacement; if not your model building data and the holdout data could have the same exact records in them.

If you really want reproducible/traceability, set the seed in `rfeControl` and `trainControl`. I'm pretty sure that you will get the same resamples across different runs (as long as the data set and resampling methods stay the same across runs).

Max

Comment: Thanks ! problem solved!I thought I used unique row indicator but it seems I did some mistake on it