# How do I set train control index of grouped cv in rfe (caret)?

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, feature-selection, rfe

I have a database with dependent observations that require a grouped resampling strategy to avoid data leakage. The outcome I'm predicting is binary. The algorithm I'm using is Random Forest (ranger). I'm interested in identifying the smallest set of features that optimize prediction (AUC score in my case). I used recursive feature elimination in caret (rfe)

My idea is to create a nested resampling with ranger tuning in the inner loop (3 splits) and feature selection in the outer loop (4 splits). I need a grouped cv in both the inner and outer loop.

I created outer indices and for each outer resampling I created inner indices.
RFE function in caret is ideal. I'm able to set index and indexOut in rfeControl (outer loop). What I wasn't able to do was set index and indexOut in trainControl (inner loop).

This post was useful to understand the issue.
[r caret package, error if I specified index for both rfe control and train control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612824/r-caret-package-error-if-i-specified-index-for-both-rfe-control-and-train-contr)

> The problem might be that the outer function (rfe) uses the same row indicators as the original data but, once train sees the data, those row numbers don't mean the same thing.

> You could do this but it will require a separate set of resampling indices for each resample of the outer model (i.e. ref) since the inner data will be different each time.

I created a separate set of indices for each resample of the outer model. It's a list of four elements (4 cv outer). Each element of the list has 3 nested sets of inner indices. But I'm not able to pass it to trainContrl. Here's my code:

```
myRFE <- caretFuncs 
myRFE$summary<-twoClassSummary
```

For specifying index for rfeControl

```
rctrl <- rfeControl(functions=myRFE,
                    method='cv', 
                    index = outerIn,
                    number=4)
```

For specifying index for trainControl

```
  tctrl <- trainControl(classProbs= TRUE,
                  method='cv',
                  number=3,
                  index = innerIn,
                  summaryFunction =  twoClassSummary)
 

  tgrid <- expand.grid(splitrule = 'gini',
           mtry = c(5:15),
           min.node.size= c(150,500,1000,2500))

  rfe_ens<-rfe(x=x,
               y=y,
               rfeControl = rctrl,
               method='ranger',
               importance = 'permutation',
               metric = c("ROC"),
               tuneGrid = tgrid,
               trControl=tctrl)
```

I've got this error

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "`index` should be lists of integers."
```

How can I tackle this issue? Any idea about it?
Thank you

More details

```
>str(outerIn)


    List of 4
 $ Fold1: int [1:24720] 7212 1429 13440 22887 9774 20582 1374 7601 9179 9099 ...
 $ Fold2: int [1:25275] 18575 11205 30522 13212 12077 7052 5298 8181 28143 18792 ...
 $ Fold3: int [1:25269] 32261 16336 25596 23698 20896 16454 32939 6595 25479 14207 ...
 $ Fold4: int [1:25032] 31789 12556 14823 23106 15732 18571 5879 11311 13302 6193 ...



>str(innerIn)


 List of 4
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : int [1:16765] 13399 3499 12636 31860 3711 23795 13953 16517 31239 868 ...
  ..$ : int [1:16280] 10255 24390 10104 11288 11282 33230 5666 21285 24531 6708 ...
  ..$ : int [1:16395] 17765 16051 1374 13273 22643 2984 11388 13944 9538 2260 ...
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : int [1:16759] 19490 10627 1060 3853 25696 9679 28456 14230 29989 7830 ...
  ..$ : int [1:16527] 32816 19534 24884 25402 27611 23251 27084 18135 13758 9663 ...
  ..$ : int [1:17264] 22451 13223 14577 16678 29490 17251 9949 30096 25587 15406 ...
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : int [1:16615] 32797 12427 4317 31676 6545 17228 15351 2585 7714 21658 ...
  ..$ : int [1:16960] 23015 29352 11955 22002 20736 8722 28758 13162 3013 29056 ...
  ..$ : int [1:16963] 3085 1171 27595 4898 3977 19213 31180 4953 11275 5629 ...
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : int [1:16521] 14597 16094 7625 32268 30646 16106 24784 13249 22954 1440 ...
  ..$ : int [1:16939] 31553 14039 10004 21405 12654 26446 10917 5330 14877 27735 ...
  ..$ : int [1:16604] 1994 25990 6935 13210 27014 31580 18450 3894 4761 4624 ...
```

Comment: a bit hard to reproduce your error if we can't recreate your index.

Comment: I apologize for that. I've edited the post with simplified the code and some info about indices structure. The problem is the nested list (innerIn). With a simple (non-nested) list it works. But since the hp tuning is nested in the process I should provide a " separate set of resampling indices for each resample of the outer model".